# OpenGL "Invalid operation error" After glDrawElements function on android phone

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I can't run my app on my phone, and I'v located the error, yet lack the knowledge in programming and in english to repair it. 
The app run's on emulator perfectly, without any errors in code neither in opengl. Yet on the phone everything runs fine without any errors, but show no opengl elements which i want to draw. I'v added `glGetError` almost everythere in my code, and found the error 1282 generated after `glDrawElements` which is `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`.

`GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is generated if a non-zero buffer object name is bound to an
            enabled array or the element array and the buffer object's data store is currently mapped.

`GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is generated if glDrawElements is executed between
            the execution of glBegin and the corresponding glEnd.

I have no glBegin or glEnd in my code, so i guess the problem is in my indexbuffer. Below i present you everthing i have with the indexbuffer.

```
private ShortBuffer _indexBuffer;

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    FramesPerSecond.StartCounter();
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, _vertexBuffer);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, -1f, -1.0f + -1.5f * i);

        gl.glRotatef(-_xAngle, 1f, 0f, 0f);
        gl.glRotatef(-_yAngle, 0f, 1f, 0f);
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, _nrOfVertices, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, _indexBuffer);            
        Log.e("Warning", " error code " +gl.glGetError());
    }
```

Code of buffer in my object initialization function:

```
    short[] indeksai = new short[] {
            0, 1, 3, 
            0, 2, 1, 
            0, 3, 2, 
            1, 2, 3, 
    };

    ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indeksai.length * 2);
    ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    _indexBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();
    _indexBuffer.put(indeksai);
```

And that's basicaly everything i have done with this buffer.

On surfaceCreated function >>

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onSurfaceCreated()");
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    float ratio = _width / _height;
    gl.glOrthof(-1, 1, -1 / ratio, 1 / ratio, 0.01f, 100.0f);
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, (int) _width, (int) _height);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
initTriangle(gl, context);
try {
loadGLTexture(gl);
    } catch (IOException e) {
   Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Texture fail");
    }
   gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);            
   gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);            
   gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);    
   gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);                     
   gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);            
   gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);             
  gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);


}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you initialize OpenGL?

Comment: I'v added onSurfaceCreated function, i guess this is what you'v asked for :)?

Comment: And who invokes `onDrawFrame()`?

Comment: Hmm, not me. It is done automaticly each time the body has to be redrawn, it is called correctly in emulator and in phone, well at least the program get's in it and run's through the code. The app works flawlessly on emulator. But gets this error on my htc desire

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's most likely because you're enabling `GL_COLOR_ARRAY` but never actually setting the `glColorPointer`.  Try commenting out the `gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);` line.

Comment: Yes. This fixed everything, that was a leftover from my tryouts with coloring the object, instead of puting a texture on it... Thank you very much !